# How can an inbound connection route to 0.0.0.0 on my server so that the original url in the logs show 0.0.0.0 and not the server IP?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Saw a connection comming in which gave a 404, but instead of showing the original URL as `www.serveraddress.com` or `https://serverip` it showed `https://0.0.0.0`. How is this possible? How can I prevent this on Ubuntu?

The log shows this:

`63.XX.XX.X - - [12/Mar/2024:10:15:27 +0000] "GET /remote/fgt_lang?lang=/../../../..//////////dev/cmdb/sslvpn_websession HTTP/1.0" 404 12863 "-" "Report Runner"`

It does not show the original full url request. That was displayed on a  custom auditing system we have. What I can see, is a mod proxy function was used which does not show in any server log which I can see.

Comment: Is it something to do with mod proxy?

Comment: Please show us all the details of that connection.

Comment: @harrymc updated

Comment: I don't see `0.0.0.0` in that.

Comment: @harrymc my problem too. Our internal auditing software uses the original URL and the 0.0.0.0 would have at to be part of the header. Other place where I can look for full header used during this request? Otherwise we would have to start saving full headers in our own auditing software

Comment: I can't answer for your auditing software, and not only because you haven't given us its name.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is just to block inbound traffic to your server by use of your server's IP address in the server block of the Nginx settings:

```
if ($host != $server_name) {
    return 444;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).